# Checking for value in a dictionary in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a dataframe with pandas (imported from a json file). There's a column "ingredients" with a dictionary value:

```
df.loc[0]['ingredients']

[{'unit': 'cl', 'amount': 6, 'ingredient': 'Milk'},
 {'unit': 'cl', 'amount': 1.5, 'ingredient': 'Soda'},
 {'unit': 'cl', 'amount': 0.75, 'ingredient': 'Sugar Syrup'}]
```

What condition should I use with `.loc` to check against a specific value in the dictionary? For example, I want to make a series with rows, whose dictionary contains "Milk".

I could only achieve this with `.iterrows()`, but I'd like to avoid iterating if possible

```
        ingredient = "Milk"
        found_matches = []
        for index, recipe in recipe_book.iterrows():
            for item in recipe['ingredients']:
                try:
                    if ingredient in item['ingredient']:
                        found_matches.append(recipe['name'])
                except KeyError:
                    continue

        return sorted(found_matches)
```

Comment: Please include ***both*** example data and the desired results from your example data, as directed here; [mre]